# How to remove contextual help on WP 3.3.2?

Tags: contextual-help

How to remove the contextual help and its tab completely from Wordpress v3.3.2? The add_filter for contextual help that used to work like wonder on older version no longer work now.

Update: (trimmed solution from Chip Bennett)

```
function wpse50787_remove_contextual_help() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse50787_remove_contextual_help' );
```

Comment: What contextual help are you trying to remove: a Theme/Plugin-specific page contextual help, or **all** contextual help?

Comment: Default wordpress contextual help for all screens. Basically the tab and anything you see when the tab drops.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since WordPress 3.3, contextual help tabs are added via the [Screen object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen), using [`add_help_tab()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_help_tab). The basic structure is as follows:

```
<?php
$screen = get_current_screen();
$screen->add_help_tab( array(
    'id'      => 'sfc-base',
    'title'   => __('Connecting to Facebook', 'sfc'),
    'content' => "HTML for help content",
) );
?>
```

If you know the `$id` of a specific help tab, you can remove it using `remove_help_tab()`:

```
<?php
$screen = get_current_screen();
$screen->remove_help_tab( $id );
?>
```

If you want to remove *all* help tabs from the current screen, use `remove_help_tabs()`:

```
<?php
$screen = get_current_screen();
$screen->remove_help_tabs();
?>
```

**You just need to wrap that in a callback hooked into `admin_head`, and you're good to go:**

```
<?php
function wpse50787_remove_contextual_help() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse50787_remove_contextual_help' );
?>
```

Some of these functions aren't well-documented in the Codex yet. Try source directly; they are defined in [`/wp-admin/includes/screen.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-admin/includes/screen.php).

#### Caveat

As-written, these functions will act *globally*. Most users will want to target a Theme- or Plugin-specific page for doing something like this. If you want to target a specific Theme's screens, you'll need to use the Theme-specific hook, e.g.:

```
<?php
global $wpse50787_options_page;
$wpse50787_options_page = add_theme_page( $args );
?>
```

Note that, at this point, you can also *hook into* the `load` action for your page-specific hook, to execute your contextual help callback:

```
<?php
global $wpse50787_options_page;
$wpse50787_options_page = add_theme_page( $args );

// Load contextual help
add_action( 'load-' . $wpse50787_options_page, 'wpse50787_remove_contextual_help' );
?>
```

Then, query for that hook in your callback:

```
<?php
function wpse50787_remove_contextual_help() {
    // Get Theme-specific page hook
    global $wpse50787_options_page;
    // Get current screen
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    // Determine if we're on our Theme-specific page
    if ( $wpse50787_options_page != $screen->id ) {
        return;
    } else {
        $screen->remove_help_tabs();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just tried the code, got "Fatal error: Call to a member function remove_help_tabs() on a non-object" on this line "$screen->remove_help_tabs();" Anything else I need?

Comment: Try hooking into `admin_head` instead of `admin_init`?

Comment: did admin_head, no more error, but the help tab and its content still stick. Any suggestion?

Comment: Okay, try one other hook: `global $pagenow; add_action( 'load-' . $pagenow, 'wpse50787_remove_contextual_help' );`

Comment: that hook doesn't work either, but I shorten your original code, and it worked. I'll edit my original post and put the code there. Thanks.

Comment: Your edited code is **exactly** what I have in my example. I'm not sure what you "trimmed"? :)

Comment: I used the final code you gave, and that's what I meant by trimmed. The code you mentioned the middle, I assumed then it was a by-product. Anyhow, that's the working version. Thank you.

Comment: I thought that might be it. :) The bit that I **bolded** was intended to be your answer. Everything after that (the **Caveat**) was for later users, who would want to remove contextual help *only* from their Plugin/Theme-specific page. Sorry for the confusion. :)